# HTML Not Changing Button Text

Tags: javascript, html

My code is very simple, but I can't figure out how to change the button text. Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id = mybutton> Hello</button>
        <script>
            function onclick(){
            document.getElementById("mybutton").innerHTML="Hi";
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can somebody figure out why this is happening? Thanks.
EDIT:
Also note, I'd like for onclick() to be called when the button is clicked.

Comment: Seems like you are starting with Javascript and got stuck with a (very basic) problem. You should have first tried to find out how to set up event listeners like `onclick` by searching. You would have found tons ...

Comment: Start study javascript [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to catch the element with `getElementById` and then bind an event listener to it, than just refering to it directly from the DOM.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("mybutton"); //catch the elem
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() { //bind 'click' event to it
      this.innerHTML = 'Hi!'; //if clicked, change the clicked element text to 'Hi!'
    }); //this keyword refers to the clicked element, but it can be also just elem.innerHTML = 'Hi!'
```

```html
<button id='mybutton'>Hello</button>
```

Comment: When I try this, the method being executed instantly.

Answer (score -1):

You've defined a function `onclick` that will, when called, modify the display text of your button.

… you never do anything to call that function.

You don't call it explicitly. You don't attach it as event listener. You don't pass it as an argument to `setTimeout`. You simply ignore it.

```js
function onclick() {
  document.getElementById("mybutton").innerHTML = "Hi";
}

onclick();
```

```html
<button id=mybutton> Hello</button>
```

Comment: I see. How do I assign that?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't bind the onclick event to any element. This should work

```
<button onclick="this.innerHTML = "hi"> Hello</button>
```

Or bind events in Javascript

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = function() { this.innerHTML = "hi" }
```

or

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click",function() { this.innerHTML = "hi" });
```

or

```
function edit() { document.getElementById("mybutton").innerHTML = "hi" }
```

and then either

```
<button onclick="edit()"></button>
```

or

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click",edit);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that better use will be:

```
<body>
<button id="myButton" onclick="onclick">
</body>
<script>
function onclick() {
  document.getElementById("mybutton").innerHTML = "Hi";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this simple code.

```js
function clickEvent(){
    document.getElementById("mybutton").innerText="Hi";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="mybutton" onclick="clickEvent()"> Hello</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the "onClick" to the button:

```
<button id=mybutton onClick="buttonclick()"> Hello</button>
<script>
function buttonclick() {
document.getElementById("mybutton").innerHTML = "Hi";
}
</script>
```